# Getting the variable from a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I am a newbie in python and there is a variable that I would like to carry over outside a for loop, the code is below:

```
positive_slopes=[[rows[p - q][q]
             for q in range(max(p-column_length+1,0), min(p+1, row_length))]
            for p in range(column_length + row_length - 1)]
```

In this case I would like to get all values of [p-q] and [q] but I don't really know how to manipulate this code,it essentially breaks when I try to change something.

I tried using a normal `for` loop but does not give the same result as the code above.The `for` loop code I tried to use is:

```
for p in range(column_length + row_length - 1):
    for q in range(max(p-column_length+1,0), min(p+1, row_length)):
            positive_slopes.append(rows[p - q][q])
```

This does not quite give the same results with the list comprehension code. This gives an output of:

```
['e', 'a', 'a', 'g', 'l', 'h', 'r', 'o', 'l', 'a', 'i', 'h', 'h', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'a', 'e', 'l', 'h', 'h', 'h', 'i', 'y', 'l', 'o', 'o', 'h', 'l', 'a', 'o', 'l', 'a', 'h', 'h', 'e', 'y', 'o', 'u', 'a', 'l', 'i', 'y', 'l', 'a', 'u', 'l', 'h', 'o']
```

The list comprehension gives me this:

```
[['e'], ['a', 'a'], ['g', 'l', 'h'], ['r', 'o', 'l', 'a'], ['i', 'h', 'h', 'e', 'e'], ['i', 'a', 'e', 'l', 'h', 'h'], ['h', 'i', 'y', 'l', 'o', 'o', 'h'], ['l', 'a', 'o', 'l', 'a', 'h'], ['h', 'e', 'y', 'o', 'u'], ['a', 'l', 'i', 'y'], ['l', 'a', 'u'], ['l', 'h'], ['o']]
```

The elements of both outputs are the same however I would like the for loop to group the letters like the list comprehension did. What am I missing in my `for` loop to give me the same output. Any help would be gladly appreciated!

Comment: Which value of (p-q)? They are different for every iteration of the loops. What do you mean by 'get the value'? What do you want to do with them? Please clarify your question. Also, if you want do to something more here, you should use normal `for` loops rather than a list comprehension.

Comment: I do not mean to be condescending here, but if you are a newbie in Python, may be List Comprehension is not a good idea to start with. Another thing, what you are asking is possible in list comprehension, but it would look ugly, and unstructured. Hint: You can run the same command, just replace `rows[p - q][q]` with `p-q`.

Comment: Edited the question! Sorry for ambiguity a while ago.

Comment: Yeah, @SayandipDutta I am spinning my head when it comes to list comprehensions. So I tried to convert it to a `for` loop. But, it won't give me the same result. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your edited code should be something like:

```
for p in range(column_length + row_length - 1):
    tempList = []
    for q in range(max(p-column_length+1,0), min(p+1, row_length)):
            tempList.append(rows[p - q][q])
    positive_slopes.append(tempList)
```